# Paypal: Unable to process payments

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using woocommerce/paypal plugin in wordpress.

I have the following request params:

```
WC_Gateway_PPEC_Client::_request: remote request to https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp with params: Array (
    [LOGOIMG] => 
    [HDRIMG] => 
    [PAGESTYLE] => 
    [BRANDNAME] => Neeta Sinha
    [RETURNURL] => http://172.16.60.51/project/our-services/checkout/?woo-paypal-return=true
    [CANCELURL] => http://172.16.60.51/project/our-services/cart/?woo-paypal-cancel=true
    [ADDROVERRIDE] => 1
    [LANDINGPAGE] => Billing
    [SOLUTIONTYPE] => Sole
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION] => sale
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ALLOWEDPAYMENTMETHOD] => InstantPaymentOnly
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT] => 0
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT] => 0
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM] => 
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM] => 
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => INR
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 29500
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 25000
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 0
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 4500
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT] => 0
    [NOSHIPPING] => 1
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME] => Dushyant Joshi
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET] => 
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2] => 
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY] => 
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE] => MH
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP] => 410209
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => IN
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Astro Architecture - Floor plan consultation
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0] => 
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 25000
    [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
    [VERSION] => 120.0
    [USER] => dushyant********india_api1.gmail.com
    [PWD] => W7HCKTAXQ4E65W92
    [SUBJECT] => dushyant******india@gmail.com
    [SIGNATURE] => AR.****************-Mmt9dEZz15ueaFPrdp
)
```

And I receive the following response

```
WC_Gateway_PPEC_Client::_process_response: acknowleged response body: Array
(
    [TOKEN] => EC-3L302863EG4314630
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2019-02-21T13:08:58Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 7a536ac5ad1e
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 120.0
    [BUILD] => 51861407
)
```

The country merchant sandbox account is India.

But I am receving the following error.

> We aren't able to process your payment using your PayPal account at
>   this time. Please go back to the merchant and try using a different
>   payment method.

Comment: check your account for permissions.

Comment: @devpro, working for US

Comment: yes, check you permission for your region.

Comment: @devpro 3rd party permissions?

Comment: yes, maybe this services is not enable in your country

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Woocommerce Plugin for Indian Merchant try enabling "Woocommerce Paypal Checkout Gateway" by WooCommerce.Note that India buyers can make payments in INR using Indian PayPal Account. However to test in Sandbox make sure you passing INR from checkout page for Indian buyers to make payments for Indian Merchant.